# How to hide field by inheritance in Odoo10

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10, inventory

I'm trying to hide field in inventory 'invoicing policy' by inheritance but i'm getting error on terminal and when i'm hiding this group then it also show error " ValueError: Element '' cannot be located in parent view".

*My code is below:*

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="inventory_rental_order_form">
<field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view"/>
<field name="name">Inventory Rental Form</field>
<field name="model">product.template</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <data>
        <xpath expr="//notebook/page[@name='invoicing']/group[2]" position="replace" invisible="1">
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='invoice_policy']" position="replace" invisible="1">
        </xpath>
    </data>
</field>
```

[image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/52746972/4451876

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 <data>
    <xpath expr="//notebook/page[@name='invoicing']/group[2]" position="attributes">
       <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
     </xpath>
     <xpath expr="//field[@name='invoice_policy']" position="attributes">
         <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
     </xpath>
 </data>
```